# Highlight repeatable badges

Tags: feature-request, badges

Some badges can be won once, some others are repeatable.

I didn't figure this out at first, since it's just not written anywhere that I can see.

Moreover, looking at the badge list, it doesn't say which are repeatable and which are not.

I think repeatable badges should be slightly different, such as having a slightly different color of background, or any other cosmetic difference (and this difference should be explained in the badges tab).

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it does. Click through and read the text of the badge closely.

> First answer was accepted with score of 10 or more. **This badge can be awarded multiple times.**

Comment: Oh, true. But it does not appear in the list of all badges: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/badges